# How to compare the fields taken through a form to those of a model created in django?

Tags: django, forms, object, post, model

I have created a Customer model in my models and registered it on admin.py. Then I made a login form and took field values using get method.Now I want to iterate through all the objects of customer created and find the one with those two matching fields.I have made a login function in the views.py. This is my model:class Customer(models.Model):

```
FirstName = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
LastName = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
address = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="")
EmailId = models.CharField(max_length=120, default="")
PhoneNo = models.CharField(max_length=12, default="")
Password = models.CharField(max_length=120, default="")
```

And this is my function:
def login(request):

```
if request.method=="POST":
    FirstName= request.POST.get('FirstName', '')
    Password = request.POST.get('Password', '')
    for customer in Customer.objects.all():
        if  FirstName==customer.FirstName and Password==customer.Password:
            return redirect ( 'customer-home')
return render(request, 'customer/login.html')
```

I'm not getting the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest instead of using the for loop to check every object you can use the Queryset check (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/) provided by Django like below

```
customer = Customer.objects.get(firstname=firstname, password=password)
if customer is not None:
  redirect ( 'customer-home')
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a form.py file which has django forms imported in it like this which would be helpful.

```
forms.py


from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import *
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import User
from django import forms

class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=['Firstname','Lastname','EmailId','Address',Password','PhoneNo']
```

Then in views add

```
from .forms import *
 def login(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':

        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password =request.POST.get('password')

        customer = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        if customer is not None:

            login(request, customer)
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Username OR password is incorrect')
        return render(request, 'customer/login.html')
```

Hope you have made a register page as it is necessary for authentication.Tell me if you need help in that

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't want to use the user authentication service. That is in my project I have three different types of users, so I'm trying to make a database of each type which will be filled through forms i.e each time a person fills a registration form that object will be of the customer model and not the users of the user authentication system. Suggest me to make login page for that or is their any other way to do what I'm trying to do??

Comment: Yes there is a simple way to solve your problem keep a single login form and use decorators for the user access like for eg if you wish that customer1 cant see the products page then you can restrict him the access.if you like this idea let me know i will tell you how to move further and do like the answer.Thanks!

Comment: Yes please do help me with this. I used a simple registration form to take in the customer information and now I want to make a login page for customer. But that should not be included in the user authentication system.Please help me with this.

Comment: Please explain what you are making and what your project is  in detail then i will tell what to do